# No toma los valores correctos en mi SELECT

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Realize mi BD con mi **tabla principal "trabajador"**, y que dependen otras de ella un ejemplo es mi tabla **"nomina" con los campos: id_nomina y descripcion_nomina**, lo que pretendo con esto es que se inserte o modifique a través del ID y que muestre a la interfaz la descripción, hasta este punto no tengo ninguno problema ya que lo realiza.

Mi problema es el siguiente, esta es una parte de mi formulario para modificar los registros, **es decir si yo anteriormente ingrese "Quincenal" (con id_nomina= 2) quiero que al acceder a mi modulo de modificaciones me aparezca por defaul en mi select el valor que yo inserte que seria "Quincenal" el problema que tengo es que no me aparece el que yo inserte, me aparece el primer registro que esta dado de alta en mi tabla de "nomina" ("Semanal=1")**, no me respeta los valores que se le insertaron previamente en la BD.

**

```html
 <?php
  extract($_GET);
  require("connect_db.php");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM trabajador  WHERE id_control=$id_control";
 //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
  $ressql=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row ($ressql)){
       
                $id_control=$row[0];
       $nombre=$row[1];
    $ap_paterno=$row[2];
    $ap_materno=$row[3];
    $NSS=$row[4];
    $CURP=$row[5];
    $RFC=$row[6];
    $id_puesto=$row[7];
    $id_area=$row[8];
    $idctg_turno=$row[9];
    $idctg_empresa=$row[10];
    $id_nomina=$row[11];
      
      }



  ?>

  <form action="ejecutaactualizar_trabajador.php" method="post">
    No. Control:<br><input type="text" name="id_control" value= "<?php echo $id_control?>" readonly="readonly"><br>
    Nombre:<br> <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>"><br>
    Apellido Paterno:<br> <input type="text" name="ap_paterno" value="<?php echo $ap_paterno?>"><br>
    Apellido Materno:<br> <input type="text" name="ap_materno" value="<?php echo $ap_materno?>"><br>
    NSS:<br> <input type="text" name="NSS" value="<?php echo $NSS?>"><br>
    CURP:<br> <input type="text" name="CURP" value="<?php echo $CURP?>"><br>
    RFC:<br> <input type="text" name="RFC" value="<?php echo $RFC?>"><br>
    Puesto:<br> <input type="text" name="id_puesto" value="<?php echo $id_puesto?>"><br>
    



<label>Tipo de Puesto</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_puesto]\">$row[descripcion_puesto] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_area" name="id_area" placeholder="Area" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>



    
 


<label>Tipo de Área</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_area, descripcion_area FROM area";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_area]\">$row[descripcion_area] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_area" name="id_area" placeholder="Area" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

 
  
<label>Tipo de Turno</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>
    
<select type="text"  id="idctg_turno" name="id_ctg_turno" placeholder="Turno" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
    






    
<label>Tipo de Empresa</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_empresa, descripcion_empresa FROM empresa";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_empresa]\">$row[descripcion_empresa] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_empresa" name="id_empresa" placeholder="Empresa" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>





 
    
   

<label>Tipo de Nómina</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_nomina, descripcion_nomina FROM nomina";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_nomina]\">$row[descripcion_nomina] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_nomina" name="id_nomina" placeholder="Nomina" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
   </form>

      
  
  
  <div class="span8">
  
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <br/>

 
  </body>
</html>
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando generas el option del select debes marcar como `selected` la opción por defecto, para ello puedes utilizar un condicional

Ejemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($row['id_puesto'] == $id_puesto) {

      $option.="<option value=\"$row['id_puesto']\" selected=\"selected\">$row['descripcion_puesto'] </option>"; 
      continue;  
    }

    $option.="<option value=\"$row['id_puesto']\">$row['descripcion_puesto'] </option>";   

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta pero implementando tu codigo me sale el siguiente error   Notice: Use of undefined constant id_puesto - assumed 'id_puesto' in line 153 . Es en el IF

Comment: @Carlos Si no me di cuenta copie tal cual de tu ejemplo y no me di cuenta de que te faltan las comillas en `$row[id_puesto]` deberia ser `$row['id_puesto']` lo mismo con el resto de `$row[]` que utilizas . Corregido en la respuesta.

Comment: Aun no me toma los valores por default sigue tomando el primero que se encuentra en la tabla correspondiente.

Comment: @Carlos Es raro, revisa el código html generado para ver que no haya ningún error. ¿Seguro que tiene algún id_puesto ya insertado? Entiendo que $id_puesto contiene un FK existente en la tabla trabajadores y PK en la tabla puesto. Una cosa que no entiendo es por ue haces un DISTINCT si el que PK es unico

Comment: Muchas garcías, si tenia error en mi código, solo otra consulta como traigo de la misma forma la fecha con la que ingrese

Comment: @Carlos dezconozco el contexto de donde traes la fecha en el codigo expuesto no veo nada relacionado con fecha, pero basicamente seria en el value como haces con los otros input entiendo

Comment: anexe el codigo ya modificado con el que tu me hiciste el favor de mostrarme, ahi ya anexe tambien lo de la fecha pero solo me muestra  en el imput dd-mm-yyy

Comment: @Carlos es mejor que habras una pregunta nueva y devuelvas esta al estado antes de la edicion para que otros usuarios con un problema similar no pierdan el contexto. No me queda igualmente claro el problema concreto con la fecha. como indique, mejor habre otra pregunta explicando y acotandola al problema concreto de la fecha. Un saludo.

Comment: Disculpa por la demora en responder, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda, formula una pregunta nueva. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando accedas a tu módulo de modificaciones, debes realizar una consulta a la tabla nomina con el valor del id_nomina que quieres actualizar, posteriormente mostrar esos datos.

Comment: Buenas noches de echo si hago esa consulta seleccionando  en cada select ya que son varios en el mismo modulo de modificaciones ejemplo de la tabla nomina es     $query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_nomina, descripcion_nomina FROM nomina";   Pero como comente en mi publicacion toma el primer valor que esta registrado en mi tabla "Nomina" mas no el valor con el que se inserto inicialmente

Comment: Si quieres que te muestre específicamente un registro de la tabla nomina, tu consulta debería ser de la siguiente forma: SELECT * FROM nomina  where id_nomina = 'id_que_desees_consultar'. O en si cual es tu problema?

Comment: Ok entiendo tu punto, lo que necesito es que me muestre en mi select el valor que yo inserte en mi formulario anterior es decir si yo inserte Quincenal en mi select que me aparezca efectivamente Quincenal por defaul mas no que me tome mi primer valor que esta en mi tabla..... No se si me explique